# What's wrong with this SQLite FULL JOIN statement with WHERE clause

Tags: sqlite, join, where-clause

Can any one tell me what's wrong with the following SQLite statement?

```
"SELECT * FROM PEOPLE FULL JOIN PLACES ON PEOPLE.Id = EVENTS.eventFbId WHERE PLACES.Id = '3211343'"
```

It's throwing an undefined error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `EVENTS` is undefined!
2. SQLite doesn't support `FULL JOIN`s.